# Calling Jquery method after a getter

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I was looking into jQuery Docs. and i found this exampe

```
$( "h1" ).html().addClass( "test" );
```

Why this code will not work ?
How getter and setter work with jQUery ?

**EDIT**

> If i want to add class to particular tag then how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because `$(selector).html()` returns a string value which makes up the HTML contents of the element you selected. Strings don't have an `addClass` function.

**Edit:** In response to your edit, merely flip around the order of your function calls.

```
$("h1").addClass("test").html()
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `html()` returns a string. It's like

```
$( "h1" ).html().addClass("test");
// is like
var test1 = $( "h1" ).html();
test1 = test1.addClass( "test" ); // will fail because string has no addClass
```

But if you `addClass` first, it will add a class to `h1` *and* return the jQuery object for `h1`, thus we can still use `html()` on it. It's like

```
$( "h1" ).addClass( "test" ).html();
// is like
var test1 = $( "h1" ).addClass( "test" ); // test1 is a jQuery object of h1
test1 = test1.html(); // success, because test1 is a jQuery object (has .html()).
```

Answer (score 0):

html() returns string so you cannot call addClass method which is suppose to be run on jQuery object

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, getters *get* certain information. The above getter, for example, gets the `innerHTML` property of the `$("h1")` jQuery object.

Setters, on the other hand, *alter* information from an element. Setters will alter the information and then *return the new jQuery object*. This is also true for all (or at least most) jQuery methods that are not getters.

Because `.html()` without arguments is a *getter*, it returns a string, *not the jQuery object*. If you were to, however, use the `.html()` method as a *setter* with an argument, it would *return the jQuery object*. This is how methods of jQuery objects returned by methods work: You can call method after method in one line of code because the methods return jQuery objects. This doesn't work if one of the methods is a getter, however.

```
$("h1").html().addClass(test); //TypeError: undefined is not a function (Chrome)
$("h1").html("Hi!").addClass(test); //Perfectly valid
```

[This tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) explains how to chain jQuery methods.